# Aligning grid columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a blog template. `section#header` is made using `flexbox`. `section.main` is made with `css grid`.

The issue is with `div.most-read` (I've changed it's bg to red). I was expecting it to be 20px(grid-gap) under `div.ad`, however, it appeared just below the expected place. What is wrong? Any ideas to overall code improvement? P.S. can't post due to the lack of words, so Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, saepe.

See the code below:

```css
:root {
  --light-dark: #333;
  --dark: #303030;
  --grey: #ccc;
  --main-bg: #ededed;
  --section-bg: #e2e2e2;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: var(--light-dark);
}

.nav li {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.tags {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: var(--dark);
}

.tags ul {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--dark);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
}

.tags li {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.tags a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 2px 0;
  color: var(--grey);
}

.tags a:hover {
  transition: .1s;
  border-top: 2px solid var(--grey);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--grey);
}

#main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

#main>* {
  background-color: var(--section-bg);
}

.latest {
  height: 80em;
  grid-column: 1 /4;
}

.ad {
  height: 25em;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}

.most-read {
  height: 55em;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!--Header-->
<section id="header">
  <header>
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="tags">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Main-->
<section id="main">
  <div class="latest">
  </div>
  <div class="ad"></div>
  <div class="most-read"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grid is drawn rows by rows and columns by columns, to allow `.most-read` to climb up, you actually need `.latest` to span across at least 2 rows to include 2 elements aside (2 rows).

you can add : 
  `grid-row: 1 / span 2;` or  `grid-row: auto  / span 2;` to `.latest`

```css
:root{
  --light-dark:#333;
  --dark: #303030;
  --grey: #ccc;
  --main-bg: #ededed;
  --section-bg: #e2e2e2;
}
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
body{
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
header{
  width: 80%;
  height: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav a{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: var(--light-dark);
}
.nav li{
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.nav li:last-child{
  padding-right: 0;
}
.tags{
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: var(--dark);
}
.tags ul{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--dark);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
}
.tags li{
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.tags a{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 2px 0;
  color: var(--grey);
}
.tags a:hover{
  transition: .1s;
  border-top: 2px solid var(--grey);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--grey);
}
#main{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
#main > *{
  background-color: var(--section-bg);
}
.latest{
  height: 80em;
  grid-column: 1 /4;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}
.ad{
  height: 25em;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}
.most-read{
  height: 55em;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Header-->
  <section id="header">
    <header>
      <h1>Blog</h1>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  <div class="tags">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Main-->
<section id="main">
  <div class="latest">
  </div>
  <div class="ad"></div>
  <div class="most-read"></div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

An easy reminder about grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: That worked fine, but i found out that `grid-template-areas` is working too, and it is easier for me to understand. Is it a bad practise using grid-template-areas?

Comment: @patlatka not at all, what matters mostly is to use things the most efficient way, let's say my answer was not, indeed: grid-area was the way to do here if you are using `grid-template-areas`

Answer (score 0):

You're overlooking one of the great benefits of CSS Grid: *the width and height of grid items can be defined at the container level*. You don't need to set heights at the item level (like with flexbox).

Your tallest item is set to 80em. In another column, one item is set to 25em, and the other to 55em.

So create a grid with 20 rows of 5em height each. Then set your grid areas.

It will look like this:

[image]

(Visualization using [Firefox overlay tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts).)

Here's the adjusted CSS:

```
#main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 5em); /* new */
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.latest {
  /* height: 80em; */
  grid-row: 1 / 21;      /* new */
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
.ad{
  /* height: 25em; */
  grid-row: 1 / 6;       /* new */
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}
.most-read{
  /* height: 55em; */
  grid-row: 6 / 21;      /* new */
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eaqh619d/21/)

```css
:root{
  --light-dark:#333;
  --dark: #303030;
  --grey: #ccc;
  --main-bg: #ededed;
  --section-bg: #e2e2e2;
}
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
body{
  background-color: var(--main-bg);
}
ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
header{
  width: 80%;
  height: 5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav a{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: var(--light-dark);
}
.nav li{
    padding-right: 1em;
}
.nav li:last-child{
  padding-right: 0;
}
.tags{
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: var(--dark);
}
.tags ul{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--dark);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  align-items: center;
}
.tags li{
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.tags a{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 2px 0;
  color: var(--grey);
}
.tags a:hover{
  transition: .1s;
  border-top: 2px solid var(--grey);
  border-bottom: 2px solid var(--grey);
}
#main{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 5em); /* new */
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
#main > * {
  background-color: var(--section-bg);
}
.latest {
  /* height: 80em; */
  grid-row: 1 / 21;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}
.ad{
  /* height: 25em; */
  grid-row: 1 / 6;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}
.most-read{
  /* height: 55em; */
  grid-row: 6 / 21;
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
    <header>
      <h1>Blog</h1>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  <div class="tags">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Anchor</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Main-->
<section id="main">
  <div class="latest">
  </div>
  <div class="ad"></div>
  <div class="most-read"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: What's real benefits of doing that?

Comment: Centralized control. Easier maintenance. Greater precision and flexibility. Probably more benefits, especially when dealing with a high number of items.